# Python Removing the encoded characters from a string

Tags: python, json

I have a json, for instance:

```
item = {"name": '\x84\xa2 Target', ...}
```

in a function that ends with:

```
return json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=True)
```

Running the function causes this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 6: invalid start byte

I have tried

```
return json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

But this gives the same error.

This code below does 'work', but the json that it gives out confuses other code down the road (not on my end):

```
return json.dumps(item, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

I would like to know how to just delete all 'complex' characters from any string.

Comment: have you tried `json.dumps(item).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`?

Comment: That gives a:     return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 6: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This is stupid, but appears to work:

```
"".join([c for c in json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False) if c in string.printable])
```

From

```
item = {"name": '\x84\xa2 Target'}
```

it returns

```
'{"name": " Target"}'
```

Comment: As for what's going on here: json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False) will return an actual string instead of an object, but will keep the UTF characters around. I then use list comprehension to treat the string as a list, and check each character against the printable character list, then use join to turn it back into a string.